# Manage dotfiles/configuration and ~/bin/-scripts for sets of servers

Tags: configuration, git, dotfiles

I have a few git repositories containing my config files and scripts that I use.

Of course I don't use all scripts on all machines that I have access to, e.g. no music related scripts and configs on computers that I access at my company.

Since I don't use them I also don't want them to appear in these places. So I have separated all script and config repositories so far that I can clone only these to the target machines.

This way it is getting more and more complex and given that I don't want to reinvent the wheel I'm asking you – is there a tool which can do all this?

I was thinking about something like an apt-get system: Have meta packages for my sets of servers (work|home|desktop|programming computers) and just run apt-get install work|home|... / upgrade on a machine to install it / get changes. Is there a wheel or is it yet to be invented? Of course it should be as portable as possible :-]

Thank you, best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you perhaps use git [submodules](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html)?  The git book [tutorial](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) is pretty good.